# Is the spell Words of Truth affected by sympathy?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

*Words of Truth* on page 168 of the new **Mage: the Awakening 2nd edition** lets you impart a true message to the spell's subjects:

> subjects of this spell can hear her and understand her clearly, regardless of distance, noise, or language barriers.

Does this entirely bypass sympathy? Is sympathy not needed, does it have no effect, or could you still benefit from sympathetic yantra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without adding extra factors or Reach, the default subject of a spell is still the caster or someone the caster is touching. (p.111) That means that sympathy still applies and is relevant.

Comment: Or someone the caster launches a visible bolt of magic to.